# Storing form input as local variable and using in another webpage

Tags: javascript, forms, bootstrap-4

i'm trying to store a user input from a form and then use that variable on a different page.

It seems like it should be very simple but im getting absolutely nothing back and i cant work out why.

Code on page 1:

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center" id="mySearchBar">

        <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center ">


            <h3 class="heading text-center pt-5">Search the Title Below and Find The Site It's Hosted On!</h3>

            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this blog" id="searchbar" name="searchbar ">
               <script> localStorage.setItem('loan', document.getElementById("searchbar").value );</script>
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" id='searchButton' type="submit">
                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                  </button>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Then on page two i have the following:

```
<script>
           var loan = localStorage.getItem('searchbar');
           console.log(loan);
           </script>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: this line?<script> localStorage.setItem('loan', document.getElementById("searchbar").value );</script>

Comment: That should be inside an event listener for the button click

Comment: You are setting the value as the page loads while the input still has empty value. Also you set item `'loan'` and try to get item `'searchbar'`

Comment: @ArleighHix oh yeah I see that, should have picked up on that. Could you exemplify what you mean by it being in an event listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fetch a value entered by the user you must do so *after* they enter the value. You need to use an event listener to fetch and store the value. For your use-case it would be best to wrap your inputs in a `<form>` and listen for the form submit. That way you capture the submit button's click and/or the input's enter key press.

You are using bootstrap-4 so I will assume you have jQuery imported as well.

```
<form class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center" id="mySearchBar">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center ">
    <h3 class="heading text-center pt-5">Search the Title Below and Find The Site It's Hosted On!</h3>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search this blog" id="searchbar" name="searchbar">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" id='searchButton' type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<script>
  // use a constant key string on both pages
  const searchbar_local_storage_key = 'my_unique_key_for_searchbar_value'

  // on page where you need to fetch stored value
  $(document).ready(function() {
    let stored_value = localStorage.getItem(searchbar_local_storage_key)
    console.log('searchbar localStorage value at document.ready:')
    console.log(stored_value)
  })

  // on page where you need store/overwrite the value
  $(document).ready(function() {
    let $searchbar = $('#searchbar')
    console.log('searchbar input value at document.ready:')
    console.log($searchbar.val())

    $('#mySearchBar').on('submit', function(event) {
      console.log('searchbar form submitted')
      // stop form submission if needed
      event.preventDefault()
      
      // get the current value
      let term = $searchbar.val()
      console.log('searchbar input value at form.submit:')
      console.log($searchbar.val())

      // store values
      localStorage.setItem(searchbar_local_storage_key, $searchbar.val());
      console.log('new searchbar value in localStorage:')
      console.log(localStorage.getItem(searchbar_local_storage_key))

    })
  })
  
</script>
```

See it in action here https://jsfiddle.net/chan_omega/qt510oms/
Enter a value, submit, view the output in the console and then reload the page (to simulate being on a different page). You will see the same value loaded from localStorage.

Comment: Could you maybe explain as to why the constant key string is needed? Thanks

Comment: For consistency, to insure it's unique, and to make sure you don't type it wrong (most editors have autocomplete that will fill in variable names, but they won't guess a string value)

Comment: Oh and I declared it with `const` to be sure the value is un-changed.